# How to fix HTML in Alpine.js dispatch when using in a WP Gutenberg block

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, alpine.js

I've been using a Alpine and its `$dispatch`-function on click to fill a modal with a title and text, dependent on what button is pressed. When I add this dispatch to a piece of code that is being used in a Wordpress Gutenberg block, I am not able to use HTML, since it breaks everything that comes after it.

My `@click` function:

`@click="$dispatch('modal', { title: 'Tilmeld åbent <i>hus</i>', message: 'Udfyld formularen herunder og tilmeld dig åbent hus for <strong> <?= $address; ?> </strong>'});"`

How do I fix this, so my block doesn't break, but the text is still displayed in my modal?

Comment: If I copy your click function I can use this just fine. It seems like you're missing a double quote at the end. Could it be that? That's the only thing I had to change.

Comment: @Yinci Ah no, that's just bad copy/pasting from my side! Have you tried creating a custom Gutenberg-block and using the click function to fill a modal? Because if you just use it in your code (e.g. header) and not in a block, it works fine as you state.

Comment: I don't use Wordpress, so I don't have experience with Gutenberg. Is it injecting something by chance? Perhaps something with double quotes? (If so, you should escape or replace them). Otherwise I don't think I can be of any assistance, sadly.

Comment: I answered my own question, so I have found a solution, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some way, Gutenberg-blocks don't like the closing HTML-tags in the `title` and `message`. A way to negate the block from breaking, is by replacing the `>` characters with its entity name `&gt;`.

In the end, the the dispatch still outputs the tag as `>` and can be styled by, for example, Tailwind's `prose` class.

The above click-function would look like this:

`@click="$dispatch('modal', { title: 'Tilmeld åbent <i&gt;hus</i&gt;', message: 'Udfyld formularen herunder og tilmeld dig åbent hus for <strong&gt; <?= $address; ?> </strong&gt;'});"`

It's not a pretty solution, but it works.